# best solution to sync 2 mysql databases in a laravel project

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, data-synchronization

I have a laravel project that is supposed to run in a localhost.
but we needed to add the ability to do some modification while user of the app is away from his pc that the app runs on it's host.
I know i can deploy the whole project in an online server but this solution is not an option till now.
we have only a weak online server (it's slower a lot than localhost);
so we can use this weak online server for these situations when the user wants to do some modifications remotely which would happen from time to time almost two or three times a day while the localhost will have the heavy work of the rest of the day which may be more than 3 or 4 hundreds processes a day.
i can't make the whole load on the online server while it's very slow like that and we don't need online benefits a lot, just for those two or three times remote modifications that the app user may or may not need, so i can't trade off localhost speed for online benefits which i need only two or three times a day.
what solution can i do.
i knew about master-slave and master-master replication but it's not an option too.

is there any ideas and thank you in advance.

-------------- about the two environments (local and online)------------
local is windows running xamp stack (apache, mysql, php)
server is linux (don't know actually which distro but any way i can't install any tools there ... just php packages with composer)

Comment: The limited changes available on your server mean its probably not useful in its current state. See there answers [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503392/how-to-copy-new-and-updated-rows-from-a-offline-to-an-online-database) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63210891/best-solution-to-sync-2-mysql-databases-in-a-laravel-project). Search some more. Tricky bit is resolving data when both online/offline change the same data. Have a plan for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679570/mysql-multiple-offline-databases     https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html

Comment: and @Avi i really appreciate your advise, but still i need a solution with the minimum interaction from the user which means at most a synchronize button or some thing like that if there is no automatic solution.

Comment: Ah, I thought there was an automatic solution provided on the second link I shared.

Comment: Check under headline `Automate daily MySQL synchronization via command line interface` on that arties. Hope it helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, If I were you, I will create a **sync_data** table in the application. And the sync data table will have the responsibility to record the changes occurring for various entities.

For example, if you change customer data in the localhost, you will save an entry to **sync_data** like **type=customer, id=10, action=update, synced=No**. And using a cron you can push these updates -fetching the customer record by saved id-  to your online server in regular intervals, which will not make your online server busy. Furthermore, your online users will have the latest data at least.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem for uploading my laravel project

just use FileZilla to upload your project, even with the worst internet speed you can do it.
and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: to make your uploads faster, use FTP apps like FileZilla

Comment: if you upload your laravel project, you can use localhost all day and just export the database to the server, very easy ;)

Comment: thank you @Reza the problem isn't uploading the project, i think you misunderstood the problem here.

Comment: @ Reza and i know that i can export and import database from phpmyadmin or any other mysql program but what about user without technical background and also i could do this grammatically too but this will be an issue when the database grows in size. imagine  uploading a file 200 or 300 mb more than one time a day for only two or three new records that you want to synchronize.

Comment: @ahmedshaheen if you want to make the user do it you can use SQLite and the option to sync only new records to the SQLite file on the server in your admin page [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660219/splitting-sqlite-files-for-syncing)